# Device detection in CM server showing error "Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: certificate, device-detection

We have enabled device detection in our Sitecore 10 setup. And in PreProduction it is showing the following warnings and logged when Experience Analytics is trying to process interactions:

```
WARN [Experience Analytics]: Device detection component failed to resolve device information with error: Can not get device information: provider is not initialized.
```

The provider is not initialized due to the following exception:

```
ManagedPoolThread #11 00:09:08 ERROR Could not update device detection database
Exception: System.Net.WebException
Message: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

We have done the setup as recommended by Sitecore here-
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-manager/configure-sitecore-device-detection.html#configuring-your-firewall_body

Also we checked the telnet for the below URLs in 443 port and succeeded-

1. `discovery-ces.cloud.sitecore.net`
2. `devicedetection-ces.cloud.sitecore.net`

Device detection is working from CD, only not from CM. Only one difference between CM and CD device detection setup I can think is CM site is using self-signed certificate.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be because of your using the self signed certificate.

If you use a self-signed certificate for SSL, then each client has to import the public-key certificate of the server to establish the trust relationship.

Given you have no control over the destination (and are unable to verify the certificate you are presenting is 'trusted'), then I dont believe you will be able to establish the trusted connection.

My suggestion would be to create a new certificate for the CA environment, or add some SANs to the one you are using for the CD environment and reuse that.